# How do I initialize a PyTables table column size?

Tags: python-3.x, pytables

I am doing a Monte Carlo calculation and I'd like to save the intermediate results to disk. Below is a basic version of my code. In my original version, I had a data aggregator object that would collect the results from each trajectory and then at the end calculate some statistics and write to disk, but I began to run out of memory and the files were unwieldy. I am trying instead to tack on PyTables so that I can a) flush the data to disk and b) efficiently read it back in for further processing when it's done.  I am working from [this tutorial](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html). My problem is that for each run, the data that would go into the `layer` column is a 1xn vector where n is set at the start of the script (*it's actually passed through on the command line in real life*).

Python won't let me define the table descriptor class inside the aggregator class, but the size `n` is outside the scope of the descriptor class. I'm coming from a MATLAB background, where all of the table creation and flushing to disk is hidden behind the single `matfile` command, so I'm really lost here.

How should I properly initialize my data table so that it can be seen within the aggregator object? If I should be doing this differently, how can I do the least amount of damage to my already working (except for the writing to disk) code?

```
import tables
import numpy

class Trajectory(tables.IsDescription):
    start = tables.Float32Col(shape=(1, 2))
    end = tables.Float32Col(shape=(1, 2))
    layer = tables.Float32Col(shape=(1, n)) # how do I pass n to here?

class AggregateResults(object):
    def __init__(self, n, filename):
        self.n = n
        self.h5 = tables.openFile(filename, mode="w")
        self.traj_group = self.h5.createGroup(self.h5.root, "Trajectories")
        self.traj_table = self.h5.createTable(self.traj_group, "trajectory", Trajectory, "Single Trajectory)

    def end_of_trajectory(self, results):
        trajectory = self.traj_table.row

        trajectory['start'] = results.start_position
        trajectory['end'] = results.end_position
        trajectory['layer'] = results.layer_path
        trajectory.append()
        trajectory.flush()

    def end_of_run(self):
        self.h5.close()


def do_code(aggregate):
    results = # long calculation goes here
    aggregate.end_of_trajectory(results)


main():
    filename = "filename.h5"
    n = 7
    aggregate = AggregateResults(n, filename)
    for x in range(100000):
        do_code(aggregate)

    aggregate.end_of_run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely answer my own question, but in solving a different problem, I came upon a solution. Rather than saving in a table, as above, I am saving the variable length vector as a separate array as [described here](http://www.mail-archive.com/pytables-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01207.html). Then I save each of the scalar values as an attribute of that vector.

```
class AggregateResults(object):
    def __init__(self, n, filename):
        self.n = n
        self.h5 = tables.openFile(filename, mode="w")
        self.traj_group = self.h5.createGroup(self.h5.root, "Trajectories")

    def end_of_trajectory(self, results):
        i = current_photon
        current_vector_name = "vector%2" % i
        current_vector = self.h5.create_array(self.traj_group, current_vector_name, results.layer)
        current_vector.attrs.start = results.start
        current_vector.attrs.end = results.end
        trajectory.flush()

    def end_of_run(self):
        self.h5.close()
```